# unable to resolve inner promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

Unable to resolve or come out of inner promise so I can send the data back to client side.

Code:

```
function getAmazonData(url, isRatings) {
    var parsedData;
    var ItemLookup;
    var ratingsURL;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        request(url, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            parseXML(body, function (err, parsedData) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                ItemLookup = parsedData['ItemLookupResponse'];

                if (ItemLookup && ItemLookup.Items && ItemLookup.Items.length > 0) {
                    // Request Error
                    if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Request && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request.length > 0 && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors) {
                        return reject(ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors);
                    } else if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Item) {
                        ratingsURL = ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews[0].IFrameURL[0];
                        if (isRatings) {
                            console.log('getting ratings...');
                            return new Promise(function (resolve2, reject2) {
                                request(ratingsURL, { json: true }, function (ratingsError, ratingBody) {
                                    if (ratingsError) {
                                        return reject2('Error in getting ratings');
                                    }
                                    ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews.push({ Ratings: ratingBody });
                                    resolve2(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        console.log('Resolved: ', ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
                        resolve(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

amazon_router.get('/getDetails', function (req, res, next) {
    var amazonApi = decodeURIComponent(req.query.url);
    var amzonApiUrl = amazonApi.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');
    var isRatings = decodeURIComponent(req.query.ratings);
    console.log('');
    console.log('amazon api url ', amzonApiUrl);
    console.log('');

    getAmazonData(amzonApiUrl, isRatings).then(function (err, response) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.send(response);
    });
});
```

The data is never sent after resolving promise here at LINE 10: `res.send(response);` There's something wrong with inner promise but I am not sure not do I fix it?

Comment: just use resolve, reject don't return resolve /reject

Comment: @Shubham I didn't get you

Comment: @Shubham I removed the return but still the same issue

Comment: remove from evry line and print err as well wherever you are rejcting. will help you debugging

Comment: Choose different parameter names. Your inner `resolve`, `reject`, `err` (twice) are all overshadowing the outer ones, so rename them to make them unique. Also, `var parsedData;` is never used.

Comment: @Xufox updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing callbacks and Promises. I would recommend wrapping all calls to Promises.

From the looks of it you don't need inner Promise because `request` expects a callback so you can easily resolve the outer one.

You also have some branches of `if` statements that don't call resolve or reject (marked in the code bellow with comments). You have to call resolve/reject in all branches otherwise the Promise 'might do nothing' in case it hits the branch.

```
function getAmazonData(url, isRatings) {
  var parsedData;
  var ItemLookup;
  var ratingsURL;

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      parseXML(body, function (err, parsedData) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        ItemLookup = parsedData['ItemLookupResponse'];

        if (ItemLookup && ItemLookup.Items && ItemLookup.Items.length > 0) {
          // Request Error
          if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Request && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request.length > 0 && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors) {
            reject(ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors);
          } else if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Item) {
            ratingsURL = ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews[0].IFrameURL[0];
            if (isRatings) {
              console.log('getting ratings...');
              request(ratingsURL, { json: true }, function (ratingsError, ratingBody) {
                if (ratingsError) {
                  reject(new Error('Error in getting ratings'));
                  return;
                }
                ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews.push({ Ratings: ratingBody });
                resolve(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews);
              });
            } else {
              console.log('Resolved: ', ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
              resolve(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
            }
          } else {
            // resolve or reject here
          }
        } else {
          // resolve or reject here
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Wrapping call to Promise:

```
function requestAsPromised(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(body)
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Abstracting all calls to promises?

Comment: Sorry, I meant wrapping - see the edited answer for more explanation. Hopefully it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` to return the inner promise(s),

```
function getAmazonData(url, isRatings) {
    var parsedData;
    var ItemLookup;
    var ratingsURL;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return request(url, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return parseXML(body, function (err, parsedData) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                ItemLookup = parsedData['ItemLookupResponse'];

                if (ItemLookup && ItemLookup.Items && ItemLookup.Items.length > 0) {
                    // Request Error
                    if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Request && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request.length > 0 && ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors) {
                        return reject(ItemLookup.Items[0].Request[0].Errors);
                    } else if (ItemLookup.Items[0].Item) {
                        ratingsURL = ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews[0].IFrameURL[0];
                        if (isRatings) {
                            console.log('getting ratings...');
                            return new Promise(function (resolve2, reject2) {
                                request(ratingsURL, { json: true }, function (ratingsError, ratingBody) {
                                    if (ratingsError) {
                                        return reject2('Error in getting ratings');
                                    }
                                    ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews.push({ Ratings: ratingBody });
                                    resolve2(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        console.log('Resolved: ', ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
                        return resolve(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Since it looks like Node.js code, try using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: I am not going to use nodejs

Comment: This is server side only I would be using a different server which is not nodejs for sure

Comment: I tried `return resolve2(ItemLookup.Items[0].Item[0].CustomerReviews);` but didn't work

Comment: See my code, you need to use `return` on every nested level promise

Comment: I added `return` on every nested level but still the data is not returned